# How to send a number from last child to parent through a pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent-child

So I have the parent process and 5 child processes. I want the parent to communicate with child 1, child 1 with child 2, ..., child 5 with parent.

I'm able to communicate with all the childs except from the last connection - from child 5 to the parent process.

Here's my code

```
int main(void){
pid_t child[CHILDS+1];
int aux = 0, id, i, num, pipes[CHILDS][2];

for(i = 0; i < CHILDS +1; i++){

    if((pipe(pipes[i])) == -1){
        perror("Pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }
}

id = babyMaker(child);

srand((unsigned) getpid());
num = rand() % 50 + 1;

if(id == 0){
    printf("Parent number: %d\n", num);
    close(pipes[i][0]);
    close(pipes[CHILDS][1]);

    for(i = 0; i < CHILDS; i++){
        if(i != id){
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            close(pipes[i][1]); 
        }
    }

    write((pipes[0][1]), &num, sizeof(int));
    close(pipes[0][1]);


    read(pipes[CHILDS][0], &aux, sizeof(int));

    while(wait(NULL) > 0);

    close(pipes[CHILDS][0]);

    if(aux > num){
        num = aux;
    }

    printf("Greatest number: %d\n", num);

}else{
    close(pipes[id-1][1]);
    close(pipes[id][0]);

    for(i = 0; i < CHILDS; i++){
        if(i != id && i != id-1){
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            close(pipes[i][1]); 
        }
    }

    printf("Child %d with number: %d\n",id, num);

    read((pipes[id-1][0]), &aux, sizeof(int));
    close(pipes[id-1][0]);

    if(num < aux){
        num = aux;
    }

    write((pipes[id][1]), &num, sizeof(int));
    close(pipes[id][1]);

    printf("\nChild %d received the number: %d\n", id, aux);
    exit(id);
}

return 0;
}
```

Where babyMaker is where I use the fork() returning 0 for the parent and 1 to 5 for the childs.

CHILDS is just a defined variable on the header.

I want to check if the number on the child is greater than the one received and if so send it. If not send the original number of that process. The parent prints the greatest number of all.

I've been trying to figure out but can't find what I'm missing. If you need more information let me know.

Edit 1: Since it may be relevant to run the code here's the babyMaker and the header file.

babyMaker

```
int babyMaker(pid_t *child){
int i;

for(i = 0; i < CHILDS; i++){
        if((child[i] = fork()) == 0){
            return i+1;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

head file

```
#ifndef HEAD_H

#define HEAD_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CHILDS 5

#endif
```

add the #include "head.h" on the main and everything should work

Comment: Your problem you are trying to solve with your program is essentially the same as in [Forking and Piping Processes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825489/forking-and-piping-processes-in-c).  Your current code is, of course, different.

Comment: In `if(id == 0){
    printf("Parent number: %d\n", num);
    close(pipes[i][0]);`, the value of `i` is `CHILDS+1`, so you are accessing out of bounds of the `pipes` array and the `close()` is not closing what you intended it to close.  I suspect the `i` should be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line:

```
id = babyMaker(child);
```

id is going to have a value of 1 to 5.

That means this line:

```
close(pipes[id][0]);
```

can become

```
close(pipes[5][0]);
```

which is invalid because it was defined as pipes[5][2]. It's an off-by-one error.

Also, these lines are invalid for the same reason:

```
close(pipes[CHILDS][1]);
```

```
read(pipes[CHILDS][0], &aux, sizeof(int));
```

```
close(pipes[CHILDS][0]);
```

---

Perhaps you meant this line:

```
int aux = 0, id, i, num, pipes[CHILDS][2];
```

to be this:

```
int aux = 0, id, i, num, pipes[CHILDS+1][2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although you answered my question with your last line, I don't understand why the other part is wrong.

id will have a value between 0 and 5 since for the parent process it returns 0. Also I need to make sure the correct processe are connecting...the code is working now with the  pipes[CHILDS+1][2] but I failed to understand why the other lines are not correct.

Comment: When an array is defined as "int pipes[5]", only pipes[0], pipes[1], pipes[2], pipes[3], and pipes[4] are valid. You were trying to access pipes[5] as well.

Comment: It is the same reason why you needed "pid_t child[CHILDS+1];" rather than "pid_t child[CHILDS];"

Comment: Oh ok I missunderstood your answer! I see now what you were saying!
Thanks again!