# Broken phone app in c with pipes and fork

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I have this code that should receive the number of processes to create and the message to send.
The idea is that said message is passed from the parent to the first child, and from the first child to the second, and from the second to the third...and in the end the message must pass from the last child to the parent (which I have not been able to do).
Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int nProcesos,i,estado;
    printf("++++++++ APLICACIÓN DEL TELÉFONO ROTO ++++++++ \n");  
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de procesos en la estructura:");
    scanf("%i",&nProcesos);
    
    /* ==  DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES ==*/
    int p[nProcesos][2];
    pid_t pid; 
    //int lh[nProcesos]; 
    char Buff[nProcesos][50]; 
    char BuffAux[50];   

    if(nProcesos>=512){
        printf("\n Si el valor excede los 512 no se asegura el correcto funcionamiento del programa\n");
        sleep(1);
    } 
    else if (nProcesos <= 1){
        printf("\n Error, debe ingresar 2 o mas procesos\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Ingrese el mensaje a enviar:\n ");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", Buff);
    
    /**
      0 - Lectura
      1 - Escritura
    **/
       
    for (i=1; i < nProcesos; i++) {//Creamos los procesos y pipes 
        
        if(pipe(p[i])== -1){
            printf("Error en la creacion de la pipe %d \n Terminando proceso...\n",i);
            exit(1);
        }            
        
        pid = fork();     
        if (pid > 0 ) {            
            if (i == 1) {
                /* ESCRITURA*/
                close(p[0][0]); //Cerrar Lectura Padre <--------------
                write(p[0][1], Buff[0] , strlen(Buff[0])+1);
                printf("El padre: %d, envia --> %s \n", getpid(),Buff[0]);
                close(p[0][1]); //Cerrar Escritura Padre
               
            }
            wait(&estado);                          
            if(i == nProcesos-1) {
                /* LECTURA*/
                close(p[i-1][1]);
                read(p[i-1][0], &Buff[i-1], sizeof(Buff[i-1]));
                printf("El padre: %d, recibe del hijo %d --> %s  \n", getpid(),i,Buff[i-1]);
                close(p[i-1][0]);                 
            } 
        }
        else if (pid == 0){ 
            /* LECTURA*/
            close(p[i-1][1]);
            read(p[i-1][0], Buff[i-1], sizeof(Buff[i-1]));
            printf("hijo %d con ID %d con el padre %d recibe --> %s \n", i, getpid(), getppid(),Buff[i-1]);
            close(p[i-1][0]);

            /* ESCRITURA*/
            close(p[i][0]);
            write(p[i][1], Buff[i-1] , strlen(Buff[i-1])+1);
            printf("hijo %d con ID %d con el padre %d envia -->  %s \n", i, getpid(), getppid(), Buff[i-1]);
            close(p[i][1]);             
            exit(0); 
        } 
        
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugagH.png)

I'm not quite sure that the buffer layout is right.

Comment: Use gender-neutral terms for processes on systems. Do not use gendered terms like _father_, _grandfather_, _son_, _grandson_, _brother_. Use gender-neutral terms like **parent**, **grandparent**, **child**, **grandchild**, **sibling**.

Comment: Look hard at [Forking and piping processes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19825489/15168) — it too is for a circular set of pipes, connected as you need.  You're excused for not finding it in your searching.